# How to create symbolic link to a folder using PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a symbolic link to a folder with PHP (under windows).

My source folder: dir/folders

Destination folder: sorted/date/folder

My code so far:

```
$dir = "dir/";
$iterator = new FilesystemIterator($dir);

foreach($iterator as $key => $fileInfo){

    if($fileInfo->isDir()){

        $cTime = new DateTime();
        $cTime->setTimestamp($fileInfo->getMTime());

        if(!file_exists('dates/'.$cTime->format('Y-m-d'))){
            mkdir('dates/'.$cTime->format('Y-m-d'), 077, true);
        }else{


        // symlink ( string $target , string $link )
        symlink('dates/'.$cTime->format('Y-m-d').'/'.$fileInfo->getFileName(), $fileInfo->getFileName());

        }
    }
}
```

Trowing me this error: Warning: symlink(): Could not fetch file information(error 3)

Maybe somone have a better way of doing this?

Comment: Dollars to donuts that's a permissions issue...

Comment: Running wamp in admin mode

Comment: Does `C:/wamp/www/site/newFolder/` exist?

Comment: Yes. new folder exist.

Comment: I'm not sure admin mode would necessarily give right perms, but more likely ;-)  Do you have your arguments ordered correctly?  Which folder is the extant one, and which is the "link"?

Comment: Added all of the code, i want to sort folders on date